# Why clicking a button in jquery works in Firefox/Chrome but does not work in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

Tested this on the javascript console and works in firefox/chrome but does not work in IE11. Anyone have any clue on why it is doing that?

```
$('#buttonID').click(); // this works only for firefox/chrome
```

Comment: Can't you reproduce it in Fiddle or something?

Comment: Most likely the error is coming from somewhere else... like invalid HTML or a javascript error elsewhere. We would need to see all the code.

Comment: you need a click handler or trigger click event? there is no reason it should not works unless is as mentioned in above comment

Comment: Have you watched the script execute in IE11 using the debugger (F12)?

Comment: the same script used in firefox/chrome browser works, IE11 doesn't seem to want to fire the same event as they other should. The debugger tells me that it has been fired, but the action has not. ex: if button is suppose to open a webpage, for firefox/chrome it does, not in IE though.

Comment: you will need to send a fiddle or a published version of the code so we can understand what is happening.

Comment: is there any `console.log()` in your script? if so try removing them, it wont work unless you open the debugger in IE(occurred to me)

Comment: there is no console.log() in script. works for all other buttons, but just not a specific one.

Comment: add a JS fiddle with your HTML and JS, or Show some code here, We are sitting ducks here. There can be 100s and thousands of reason why it is not working on single button.